# which one will be faster?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

let's say i have an array, size 40. and the element im looking for is in position 38.
having a simple loop, it will take 38 steps right?
but, having, 2 loops, running in parallel, and a variable, "found"
set to false, and changes to true when the element is found.

the first loop, will start from index 0
the second loop, will start from index 40.

so basically, it will take only, 4 steps right? to find the element. the worst case will be if the element is in the middle of the array. right?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It sounds like you are 'trying to reinvent the wheel' to do a search on an array.

Comment: im not trying to reinvent the wheel. i just have this question, and im trying to figure out which one will be faster

Comment: Are you simply looking for affirmation that the worst case is as you say? If it's in the 'middle' then the number of steps is the same, potentially.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. i just wanted to figure out which one will be faster.

Comment: Accessing an array is in O(1). So when accessing the value at the 38th position, you can simply do `arr[37]` or `arr[38]` (depending on the base of array indices).

Comment: If you only have 40 elements the first one is likely to be faster as the overhead of creating a thread and synchronizing between threads will dwarf a simple scan over 40 elements.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how much work it takes to synchronize the state between the two threads.

If it takes 0 work, then this will be, on average, 50% faster than a straight through algorithm.

On the other hand, if it takes more work than X, it will start to get slower (which is very likely the case).

From an algorithm standpoint, I don't think this is how you want to go. Even 2 threads is still going to be O(n) runtime. You would want to sort the data (n log n ), and then do a binary search to get the data. Especially you can sort it 1 time and use it for many searches...

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about algorithmic complexity, this is still a linear search. Just because you're searching two elements per iteration doesn't change the fact that the algorithm is O(n).

In terms of actual performance you would see, this algorithm is likely to be slower than a linear search with a single processor. Since very little work is done per-element in a search, the algorithm would be memory bound, so there would be no benefit to using multiple processors. Also, since you're searching in two locations, this algorithm would not be as cache efficient. And then, as bwawok points out, there would be a lot of time lost in synchronization.

Comment: Well its a linear search vs a parallel linear search. But I think o(.5 n) and o (n) both simplify to o (n), so you are right in no algorithm performance change ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you are running in parallel **you are dividing your CPU power into two + creating some overhead**. If you mean you are running the search on a say, **a multicore machine, with your proposed algorithm then the worse case is 20 steps.** You are not making any change in the complexity class. So where those 4 steps, that you mentioned, are coming from?

Comment: well, as i wrote, if the element is found in 38/40 position of the array, then it will be located by the second loop, on the second step.
the first loop will already have done 2 steps. so 2+2 = 4.

Answer (score 0):

**On average** there is no different in runtime.

Take for example if you are searching for an item out of 10.
The original algorithm will process in the following search order:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

The worse case is the last item (taking 10 steps).

While the second algorithm will process in the following search order:

```
 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2
```

The worse case in this scenario is item 6 (taking 10 steps).

There are some cases where algorithm 1 is faster.
There are some cases where algorithm 2 is faster.

Both take the same time **on average** - O(n).

---

On a side note, it is interesting to compare this to a binary search order (on a sorted array).

```
4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3
```

Taking at most 4 steps to complete.